# Powerbuilder 2017: How to access Outlook Web app from application

Tags: powerbuilder

My application currently uses Microsoft Outlook, our customers wants to upgrade the the functionality to use the OWA(Outlook webapp ) instead of Outlook client.

Is there any possibility to access OWA from powerbuilder. i need to open the OWA and have to write a new draft mails.

Comment: Being a web application I suspect your only options is to see what kind of API OWA has available. There might be a web services (or other) type API that you could use. But if you only need to compose mails you could use the Internet Explorer Browser OLE control, navigate to the OWA application, open the compose dialog, pre-populate data and let the user take over from there. Depending on what your requirements are- but the web browser control works nicely- I used it once to play a web based RPG game and scraped/modified elements on web page essentially using PB App to supercharge the game.

Comment: Continued- it's not real pretty using the web browser control, you need to parse the HTML manually and/or modify elements without the benefit of jQuery, and navigating DOM in PB was painful.